# Is stateless usage of Camunda dmnEngine thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, concurrency, camunda, dmn

I have a use case where I use Camunda (7.12) for a stateless DMN evaluation. So it's just a big DMN table used for mapping values. The application is written in Spring Boot in Kotlin and is exposed as a REST service.
The code looks like this:

```
    companion object {
        private const val DMN_NAME = "mappingRules.dmn"
        private const val DECISION_NAME = "mappingRules"
    }

    val dmnEngine: DmnEngine
    val dmnTableStream: InputStream
    val dmnDecision: DmnDecision

    init {
        dmnEngine = DmnEngineConfiguration.createDefaultDmnEngineConfiguration().buildEngine()
        dmnTableStream = MyMappingService::class.java.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(DMN_NAME)
        dmnDecision = dmnEngine.parseDecision(DECISION_NAME, dmnTableStream)
    }

    fun mapValue(source: String) {
        val decisionResult: DmnDecisionTableResult = dmnEngine
            .evaluateDecisionTable(dmnDecision, Variables.createVariables()
                .putValue("source", source)
            )
        return decisionResult.firstResult.getValue("target") as String
    }
```

`mapValue` and then `dmnEngine.evaluateDecisionTable` may be executed by multiple threads concurrently, is this Camunda method thread-safe? I could not find the information in the official documentation about a usage of stateless DMN evaluation and thread safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an answer in the Camunda forums, both `DmnEngine` and `DmnDecision` are supposed to be thread-safe: https://forum.camunda.org/t/re-use-caching-of-dmn-objects-in-multi-threaded-application/1576/2